why does Raydium use Q32 (u32 max + 1) when calculating the price of base/output tokens?
I was reading the Raydium CPMM code and came across Q32 constant (=u32::MAX + 1). Two questions:

what's the reasoning behind multiplying the values by Q32? is that mostly for precision (ie multiplying or dividing this number will give you basically decimal precision a bit better)?

what does the output of this token_price_x32 mean? is it correct to say the outputs are prices of X and Y in relation to each other (ie what's the price of X denominated in Y and vice-versa)?


